# ObjectListView cannot cancel item selection BeforeSelect

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I converting a standard TreeView to BrightIdeaSoftware.TreeListView

I cannot found how to convert this event

```
private void LstAgents_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    // If error save
    if (!SaveCurrentValues())
        // Keep active selection
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

How to simply cancel the user action if something was wrong with TreeListView

Thanks ...

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve from a usability perspective?

Comment: I just want that user stay with the current node selected.
I want to cancel event like AfterSelect ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to prevent the user changing the selected item when there is a validation problem with it then you can use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.  From a usability point of view it's a bit of a disaster though.  You might want to instead highlight the row in red or throw up an error dialog and revert the row.

```
private object oldSelection = null;
void LstAgents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(oldSelection != null && true/* some condition*/)
        LstAgents.SelectedObject = oldSelection;

    oldSelection = LstAgents.SelectedObject;
}
```